# How to set the location of a WPF window?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a List View in which I have defined a custom cell as a user control.

In the custom cell I given user hyperlink, I am showing a WPF dialog when user clicks on a hyperlink.

I want WPF dialog comes just above the hyperlink..

Please let me know how can I acheive this or how to set the location of the dialog so that it just comes above the hyperlink.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[Window.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.left(v=VS.100).aspx) and [Window.Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.top(v=VS.100).aspx)

```
var location = myTextBlock.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
window.Left  = location.X;
window.Top   = location.Y - window.Height;
```

Comment: Josh .. How to get the textblock (contained inside the hyperlink)

I can get the the hyperlink through event arguement "sender"..

Comment: I have defined the hyperlink as below :
<Hyperlink
                    x:Name="condOpt"
                    Click="condOpt_Click">
                    <TextBlock
                        Foreground="Blue"
                        Text="{Binding Path = SelectedOperator.Value}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Hyperlink>

Answer (score 21):

You need to set the `WindowStartupLocation` to [`Manual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstartuplocation.manual.aspx) (which is the default however) as well as setting the `Top` and `Left` property values.

> Setting [CenterScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstartuplocation.centerscreen.aspx) causes a window to be positioned in the center of the screen that contains the mouse cursor.
>
> Setting WindowStartupLocation to [CenterOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstartuplocation.centerowner.aspx) causes a window to be positioned in the center of its owner window (see Owner), if specified. The owner window can be either another WPF window or a non-WPF window.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You would need to get the coordinates of the hyperlink and then set the window position as shown here:

http://blog.fossmo.net/post/How-to-set-the-windows-position-in-WPF.aspx

To get the relative/absolute positions of elements have a look here for some tips:

http://ivolo.mit.edu/post/WPF-Mouse-and-Point-Acrobatics.aspx

Answer (score -1):

if you set .Left of the window more then monitor size (2000 works for me) window goes on second monitor and you can then "maximize"

Comment: Hard coding values to make things work on your development machine is really bad practice.