# WPF, MVVM - Set dialog window position relative to main window?

Tags: wpf

I'm creating my own DialogBox. 
How can I make this DialogBox always appear to the top right corner of my MainWindow?
I mean the dialog box should move with the MainWindow like a conjoined twins.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code from this answer to help you achieve your goal: [How to set the location of a WPF window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734810/how-to-set-the-location-of-a-wpf-window)

When you create a MyDialogBox, get the location of the current / main window and use that to help calculate where you should set the location of your MyDialogBox