# How to adjust the height of a window to the top of the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window in WPF and I need to state fit the top of the screen, the width only need 800 pixels.
I have this but not working:

```
Title="Title" Height="Auto" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanResize" Icon="/img/icon.ico" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

I also tried this but it gives error:

```
Title="Title" Height="*" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanResize" Icon="/img/icon.ico" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: See [How to set the location of a WPF window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734810/how-to-set-the-location-of-a-wpf-window)

Comment: Is there any way to do this from the xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of window to screen height and then try to set the location of the window in Window_Loaded event as follows:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var CurrentWindow = (sender as Window);
    CurrentWindow.Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    CurrentWindow.Top = 0;
    CurrentWindow.Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / 2 - CurrentWindow.Width / 2;
    CurrentWindow.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Bottom;

}
```

Comment: This works, but exceeds the taskbar, this is fixable?

Comment: @Richard I have edited the answer, please set maxheight of window

Answer (score 2):

Remove `WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"` from your Xaml code and insert `Left="0" Top="0"`. You may increase `Left` value to your needs.

**UPDATE**

Misunderstanding, I didn't get that the window should take the full screen height (except task bar).

The final solution would be:

```
<Window ... 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height}"
        Width="800" >
```