# NSDrawer-like control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to build a WPF application with a slide-out drawer like a lot of macOS applications have:

[image: NSDrawer Example]

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for ``NSDrawer``? Apple is deprecating the class, and urging developers to avoid drawer-like interfaces. If you intend to market your app on the app store, you should heed their advice, and think about an alternative way to display/gather information.

Comment: No I haven't, since my question is about how to implement something similar using WPF. Last I checked, you can't submit WPF apps to the Mac App Store...

Comment: The question is about how to implement this, not whether it's a good idea to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF you would typically display something like that using a separate child [Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) within your current window. The Popup is going to be constrained within the borders of your parent window whereas the Window can be anywhere on the screen. You can launch a new window fairly easily:

```
var window = new Window();
// Initialize your content to whatever you want in the window
window.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello world };
window.Show();
// Use .Show() if you want to allow users to interact with both windows at the same time
// Otherwise use .ShowDialog() to force the user to interact/dismiss the child first
```

You'll need to control the position of the child window somehow if you want it to be tied to the side of your parent window. [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734810/how-to-set-the-location-of-a-wpf-window) describes controlling window location. You'll probably want to do this during an event on your parent window that makes sense, like [SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [LocationChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.locationchanged.aspx).

Lastly, depending on how you want the window frame to look (I'd imagine the "drawer" isn't supposed to look like a full blown window just stuck to the side of your parent window) I would at least change the child's [WindowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Further, you could make the window transparent and totally restyle the content to look much more like what you have provided as an image.

This is roughly what you're looking for. I hope this helps.